# Can Jersey find a POJO from an ID when mapping from JSON?

Tags: java, json, jpa, jersey, eclipselink

It's hard to put this into words, but I'll do my best.

**High Level:** I am writing a web service to add a new `PrblFldr` entity to the database, but I need to associate the proper `PrblTmplt` with it (please ignore the terrible naming scheme, I didn't do it). I am POSTing JSON, which Jersey maps to the correct POJOs. But, instead of calling the POJO's constructor for one of the fields, I want it to use the `EntityManager` to find the correct object based on an ID.

**Low Level:** Here's a sample of the JSON I am currently trying to pass to my web service:

```
{
    fldrNm: "test",
    prblTmplt: {
        tmpltSeqId: 4
    }
}
```

Here's the code on the other side, where the web service sits:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/folders/create")
public Response createFolder(PrblFldr folder) {
    em.persist(folder);
    return Response.ok(gson.toJson(folder), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

Now, here's what the `PrblFldr` entity looks like, with a lot of irrelevant fields omitted:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRBL_FLDR")
@NamedQuery(name="PrblFldr.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM PrblFldr p")
public class PrblFldr implements Serializable {

    @Expose
    @Column(name="FLDR_NM")
    private String fldrNm;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to PrblTmplt
    @Expose
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FLDR_TYP_SEQ_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private PrblTmplt prblTmplt;

    // other fields...
}
```

See how that `prblTmplt` field is joined on `FLDR_TYP_SEQ_ID`? I need to get from that ID to the object. Lastly, here is what our `PrblTmplt` class looks like, again with only relevant information included:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRBL_TMPLT")
@NamedQuery(name="PrblTmplt.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM PrblTmplt p")
public class PrblTmplt implements Serializable {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Id
    @Column(name="TMPLT_SEQ_ID")
    private long tmpltSeqId;

    // other fields...
}
```

**The ultimate goal is to** prevent the need for creating some intermediate POJO that Jersey maps to, only to turn right around to fill out the relevant fields in a new `PrblFldr` object (and use `em.find()` to actually find the `PrblTmplt` we're using). I'm not sure if what I'm talking about is possible, but after searching for hours, I figured I would ask you guys.

**EDIT:** To more clearly specify my situation, the above code (when I log what the web service sends back) outputs JSON like this:

```
{
    fldrNm: "test",
    prblTmplt: {
        tmpltSeqId: 4
    }
}
```

... which is exactly what I put in. Instead, I want that `tmpltSeqId` to be used as a lookup PK to fetch the object that exists with that ID in the DB, so a return might look something like this:

```
{
    fldrNm: "test",
    prblTmplt: {
        tmpltSeqId: 4,
        tmpltDesc: "sample description",
        tmpltNm: "sample template name",
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe Jersey is using JAXB to build entities from your JSON.  You can use a setPrblTmplt() for JAXB, and have it find the PrblTmplt instance using JPA and set the field with it instead, and let JPA access the prblTmplt attribute directly.  Also JoinColumn(name="FLDR_TYP_SEQ_ID" means that the "FLDR_TYP_SEQ_ID" field is the foreign key to the PrblTmplt.tmpltSeqId, but you have marked it as read-only.  If it is mapped elsewhere in the object, why not use that field to look up the PrblTmplt from JPA rather than send a partial JSON representation through?

Comment: Considering the `tmpltSeqId` is marked as the PK, I can just as easily do something like `em.find(PrblTmplt.class, id)` to find it. The problem lies with the fact that I would either be directly interpreting the JSON coming over or creating some intermediate POJO to map to. I would love it if I could somehow make Jersey auto-lookup and map that `prblTmplt` field to the PrblFldr object, based on the `tmpltSeqId` I feed it.

Comment: Also, the reason why I marked `insertable` and `updatable` as false on the `JoinColumn` annotation for `prblTmplt` is because you shouldn't be modifying (or creating) a template from a `PrblFldr` object. The template must be modified from a completely different avenue.

Comment: I'd suggest that you'd have more easily maintainable and evolvable code if you separated your concept of JPA from your concept of JSON in your application. If you don't you wont be protected from schema migrations, etc. There will also be times when you want the JSON to not be an exact replica of the JPA entity. Many have been bitten by this before learning to just suck it up and encapsulate their various layers of abstraction.

Comment: So would you suggest creating an intermediate POJO that the JSON maps to, then? Then when JAXB actually pulls in the JSON and maps it to that POJO, I should create and persist a new entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided against my original thought of having all this happen automatically. Instead, I created my own "intermediate entity" POJOs that I have allowed JAXB to map to. I will then perform my own JPA lookups and build my actual entity manually. Looking back, this is probably a more proper way to do this since you avoid ambiguity by performing the process by hand.